# Calculating $x\oplus z + y\oplus z$ from $x+y$ without knowing $x$ nor $y$

Tags: arithmetic

I was given two numbers $k=x+y$ and $z$ s.t. $ x,y,z \in R$

I don't know the value of either x nor y, I only know k and z.
I would like to calculate $ x\oplus z+y\oplus z$ when $\oplus$ denotes the XOR operation.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @lonestudent your edition to my post is incorrect, I meant to xor the values with z, not a power.

Comment: Please post the full question. Maybe there is some other hint...

Comment: I rolled back my edit. Please, use MathJax.

Comment: @ChemistryLover Unfortunately there is not question, it is a problem I have encountered at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to know that in general.

For example, take unsigned 2-bit integers $x,y,z$ (arithmetics done after promoting to $3$-bit integers to avoid overflow) with $x+y=4$ and $z=1$.  You have two possibilities:

- $x=y=2$, so bitwise-XOR'ing with $z$ gives $x\operatorname{bitwiseXOR}z = 3 = y\operatorname{bitwiseXOR}z$ so the new sum is 6.
- $\{x,y\}=\{1,3\}$, so bitwise-XOR'ing with $z$ gives $\{0,2\}$ which sum to $2$.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> "I meant to xor the values with $z$, not a power."

Assuming that you mean the [XOR logical gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate), then this means that your range of values for $x,y,z$ are $\{0,1\}$. In this case, the XOR operation (denoted by $\oplus$) is given by
$$
x \oplus y = x+y-2xy
$$
So for your problem
$$
x \oplus z + y \oplus z = x+z-2xz+ y+z-2yz =\boxed{ 2\color{purple}{z} + (1-2\color{purple}{z})(\color{blue}{x+y}) }
$$
works for $x,y,z \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't assume x,y,z have binary values. As I stated, z is an int and so as x and y.